# Is it possible to recover the digit prompts given a phone number?

Tags: call-history

Let's say I call a number and enter a certain sequence of digits in response to the machine prompts. Is it possible to recover that sequence as part of the call history?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I guess OP is talking about entering digits in response to input asked by an  IVR system on call. OP wants to know what digits they had entered. That's my guess.

Comment: @Firelord is correct, I'm not sure how else to describe that.

Comment: depends on phone app. try another dialer from google play store